# How to match/search the value of Sheet1.Range("A1") in Sheet2.Range("A1:A10") in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say i have this value "ABC123" in `Sheet1.Range("A1")`

I want to search for/ match this value in Sheet2.Range("A1:A10") // or the column

```
If the value is found
      //msgbox "Found"
else
     //msgbox "Not found"
end if
```

Comment: Of course this can all be done with a formula: `IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Not Found","Found")`

Comment: @Joel have you checked into the answers you got below ? find the time to provide feedback to people who spent their time helping you

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim t As Long
        On Error Resume Next
        t = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If t > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Found"
        Else
            MsgBox "Not found"
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I cheated, I had answered something similar yesterday, not close enough to be a duplicate but I had this part already prepared, only needed to change the outputs.  So a quick copy and paste.

Comment: @ShaiRado btw, I was told by Mat'sMug that using early binding like mine is a little quicker than the late binding like yours.  Not sure if it is true and it definitely would not matter with a one off like this.  But just for your information.

Comment: thanks for the info. I made an experiment, tested both answers, had searched in a loop 1000 items in column A, within a range of 26 (columns) x 5000 (rows), **both ran under a second !**. I wonder how large the loop and range need to be for the differences to be noticeable ?

Comment: @ShaiRado hence the reason I stated who told me and that I was not sure it was true, but good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Match` function below (you will get the row number found):

```
Option Explicit

Sub MatchTest()

Dim MatchRes As Variant

MatchRes = Application.Match(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10"), 0)
If IsError(MatchRes) Then
    MsgBox "Not found"
Else
    MsgBox "Found at row " & MatchRes
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

    Set r1 = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    Set r2 = Sheet2.Range("A1:A10")
    s = r1.Value

    Set r3 = r2.Find(what:=s, after:=r2(1))
    If r3 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shai Rado

Answer (score 0):

just playing around a little bit with Scott's solution:

```
Sub foo2()
    Dim t As Long
    On Error GoTo NotFound
    t = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"), 0)
    MsgBox "Found
    Exit Sub      
NotFound:
    MsgBox "Not found"
End Sub
```